# Two Parts, If I read in a file that's formatted like an array, can it be treated as such? And another about searching strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, text

I have two questions with this sample of code i'm about to drop in.  The first deals with

```
person = gets.chomp
puts "Good choice!  Here are #{person}'s tags!"
person = "#{person}.txt"
file = File.open(person)
while line = file.gets do
    puts line
end
```

If the file that's opened is formatted exactly like an array (in this case its actually an array ruby has previously written to a txt file lets say, ["Funny", "Clever", "Tall", "Playboy"] )  Is there an easy way just make that an array again? Nothing I tried seemed to work.

The second deals with this

```
puts "Which tag would you like to vote on?"
tag = gets.chomp
if File.open(person).grep(/tag/) == true
    puts "Found it!"
else
    puts "Sorry Nope"
end
#f = File.new("#{person}")
#text = f.read
#if text =~ /tag/ then
#puts "Alright, I found that!"
#else
#puts "Can't find that sorry."
#exit
#end
```

This section just doesn't seem to be working.  It never finds the string, also the commented out attempt didn't work either.  I wasn't sure if the grep line actually returned a true or false value, but the commented out part avoids that and still doesn't return the string.  I tried formatting the input with "" around it and every possible configuration ruby might be looking for but it always passes to the negative result.

and for the sake of completeness here is all the code.

```
puts "This is where you get to vote on a Tag!"
puts "Whose Tags would you like to alter?"

 Dir.glob('*.txt').each do|f|
 puts f[0..-5]
 end
puts ".........."

person = gets.chomp
puts "Good choice!  Here are #{person}'s tags!"
person = "#{person}.txt"
file = File.open(person)
while line = file.gets do
    puts line
end
puts "Which tag would you like to vote on?"
tag = gets.chomp
if File.open(person).grep(tag) == true
    puts "Found it!"
else
    puts "Sorry Nope"
end
#f = File.new("#{person}")
#text = f.read
#if text =~ /tag/ then
#puts "Alright, I found that!"
#else
#puts "Can't find that sorry."
#exit
#end
```

Comment: In future, you may wish to hold off awhile before selecting a preferred answer, to encourage other (possibly better) solutions.  You may want to read over this [SO FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Part 1 - Parse a string into an array

Use [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse('["Funny", "Clever", "Tall", "Playboy"]')
# => ["Funny", "Clever", "Tall", "Playboy"]
```

---

#### Part 2 - Find a string in a file

As bjhaid recommended, use `File.read` and `include?`:

```
File.read(person).include?(tag)
```

This returns either `true` or `false`.

Comment: that was very fast :D

Comment: That's because Matt, like sawa, has one of those [quick-draw holsters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYQudvv7PWo&feature=c4-overview&list=UU8hZRQjjQgGxgOt0s0NtN_w).  Matt appears at 2:06.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's me! :)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if File.open(person).grep(tag) == true
  puts "Found it!"
else
  puts "Sorry Nope"
end
```

to

```
if File.read(person).include?(tag)
  puts "Found it!"
else
  puts "Sorry Nope"
end
```

[File#open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-open) returns an `IO` object so you can't call `grep` on it like you would have done on an array, so I would suggest [`File.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-read) which returns a `String` object that you can now call `include?` on

Comment: I think I just figured out why you shouldnt ask two questions, wont let me check both answers. :(

Comment: @ryancroker Once you get [15 points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote) on your account you can always +1 both :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are not spelling my handle correctly again **angry**

Comment: I thought that, now that we are friends, I could use your nickname.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `bjhaid` is some rigorous refinement of my Last name, and I think I don't want it to get mutated again ;) now that we are friend, be nice with it :)